# Is there a way to auto delete data from Firebase upon app being destroyed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an app in Android Studio that matches users based on location. To avoid lots of network usage, I am uploading the radius in which the "provider" services. When a "user" is looking for available services in their area, the app look only in the directory for their area. That way, it doesn't have to poll thousands, and if it get big millions, of other users to find the closest. This is all done on Firebase Real-Time Database.

The issue I am having is that I only want the "provider" to show when they are in the app logged in. This includes when the app is in the background. I have tried using onDestroy but it cannot completely finish deleting before the super is called and it halts the delete. Is there a better way to accomplish this? Here is what I am using right now:

**This code is for when the user signs out which works perfectly when clicking logout:**

```
 mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginEmail.getText().toString().trim(),
        loginPassword.getText().toString().trim()).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        MainActivity.util.changeUIState(true, getActivity());
        MainActivity.util.popupNotice(mainView.getContext(), R.string.login_successful);
        FirebaseAppUtilsHSquared fbUtil = new FirebaseAppUtilsHSquared();
        fbUtil.getUserProfileInfo(getActivity());
        MainActivity.loggedIn = true;
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
                    if (!MainActivity.firstGPSRequest) {
                        for (int x = 0; x < MainActivity.matrix[0].length; x++) {
                            for (int y = 0; y < MainActivity.matrix.length; y++) {
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(MainActivity.GPS_PATH)
                                        .child(String.valueOf(MainActivity.matrix[y][x])).removeValue();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**Here is the `onDestroy()` override. I have tried putting the code above in the on destroy as well:**

```
  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        mAuth.signOut();
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Please don't use all-caps in your question, as it is commonly perceived as yelling at people. Instead use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to put emphasis where needed.

Comment: Ok. Didn't think about that so I am sorry. Can you help me with the question please?

Comment: So you want to delete all user data when the app is destroyed?

Comment: Not user data, just items in realtime database that are used for only that session.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the super.onDestroy() after a thread delay ?

Like this

```
  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        mAuth.signOut();
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            super.onDestroy();
          }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: I tired that and since the "new Runnable()" is an inner class, it wont recognize the "super.onDestroy();"

Comment: that's unfortunate